# Is $\mathrm{End}_{KS_r}(V)$ semisimple?

Tags: modules, semi-simple-rings

If $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$, then the ring $KS_r$ is semisimple. Let $V$ be a $KS_r$-module. In particular it is semisimple. Can we assure that $\mathrm{End}_{KS_r}(V)$ is a semisimple ring?

Since $V$ is semisimple, it is a von Neumann regular ring, but this is not enough.

Comment: If $V$ finitely generated?

Answer (score 0):

I presume $S_r$ is the symmetric group on $r$ symbols? If $G$ is any finite
group, $K$ a field of characteristic zero, and $V$ is an irreducible
module then $\text{End}_{KG}(V)$ is a skew field
(Schur's lemma). More generally,
if $V$ is finitely generated, it is a finite direct sums of irreducibles
and $\text{End}_{KG}(V)$ is a direct product of matrix rings over skew fields
so semisimple.

If $V$ is not finitely generated, then its endomorphism ring is
too large to be semisimple.